# Is any $n$-parameter continuous group isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: group-theory

I know this is probably a dumb question. In a book I'm reading the following definition comes up.

> If $n$ is the minimum number of continuously varying real parameters required to characterize a continuous group, then the group is termed an *$n$-parameter continuous group.*

A little bit after, I'm asked to show that any 1-parameter continuous group is Abelian. I want to say that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, as it seems like that's essentially the definition of a 1-parameter continuous group, but I'm not too certain it's that easy.

In general, I would like to know if an $n$-parameter continuous group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. If it is not, please tell me why it isn't.

Comment: The circle group $e^{it},$ $t \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are you saying that $\mathbb{R}$ isn't isomorphic to that?

Comment: Yes. Unless you're willing to exhibit an isomorphism... $e^{i(2\pi)}$ is the identity, which never happens in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard modern language for "$n$-parameter continuous group" is "$n$-dimensional [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group)," and it is very far from true that every $n$-dimensional Lie group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, as Chappers says in the comments, the [circle group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group) $S^1$ is a $1$-dimensional Lie group which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$; they are not even homeomorphic as topological spaces, since $S^1$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}$ is not.

Starting when $n = 2$ it is also possible for a Lie group to be nonabelian, and most interesting Lie groups are.

Comment: Ah thanks. That's clear. In general, could we maybe say that an $1$-parameter continuous group is at least homomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? ($f(t_1)f(t_2)=f(t_1+t_2),\,t_1,t_2\in\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: If that is true, is there anything similar to that property for $n$-parameter continuous groups where $n>1$? (I'll open a new question for this if it's better to do that)

Comment: @Arturo: in general, an $n$-dimensional Lie group $G$ admits an interesting map from an $n$-dimensional vector space called its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$: the map $\mathfrak{g} \to G$ is called the exponential map, and if $G$ is abelian then it is a homomorphism. If $G$ is nonabelian then things get more interesting. There's a lovely story here, and you probably won't learn it properly if you're reading a source that uses the phrase "continuous group"... I mean, the term "Lie group" is over a hundred years old now.

Comment: Wow this is interesting! Is the term "continuous group" evasive or shady in any way? I know this may be pushing my boundaries here (I can technically just keep reading my book), but why is the nonabelian case more interesting? How can a restriction such as noncommutativity be 'interesting'? (A good reference would be great)

Comment: @Arturo: well, it's both imprecise and old-fashioned. It may not even mean a Lie group; it may mean a topological group, or maybe even a formal group, or who knows what else. In general, nonabelian things are a lot more interesting than abelian things. Abelian Lie groups can be completely classified: the connected ones are products of copies of $\mathbb{R}$ and $S^1$. There's not much variety there. But nonabelian Lie groups are much more interesting than this (in particular there are a lot more of them), and if you want to find out how interesting you should pick up a textbook on Lie theory.